# Collecting data from how visitors interact (client-side) with a javascripted form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, cookies, session-cookies

I'm doing educational research about how students use a web quiz as a study tool.  I've set up a web quiz that shows photos of plants and asks students to type in the correct scientific name.

http://www.plantsciences.ucdavis.edu/courses/enh6/quiz/quiz_sn.html

Using something like Google Analytics I can see the number of photos students look at (because each new photo involves a request from the server).  But I'd also like to know how many times students type in a correct answer and how many times they type in a wrong answer.  The form is all checked client-side using javascript, so giving a right or wrong answer doesn't start any communication with the server.

Is there a way to collect this data using cookies or something?  Or can I have the form request a certain single-pixel gif with each right or wrong answer, so the server can record what's happening?  Or do I need to reprogram everything and have the form get processed on the server to collect this data?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to record correct/incorrect answers, the simplest thing to do from what you've already got would be to expose an API on your server where you can send the information you want to store. Then, you can make an AJAX request to it after receiving an answer and your client side application will be nicely decoupled from the server side storage.

At this stage though, your application won't know if an error occurs on the server side of things. This may be what you want to happen if such errors shouldn't affect your application's primary behavior, but you may wish to respond with a success/error (most likely using JSON) to allow your application to react accordingly.

Comment: I'm sure this is technically correct but, unfortunately, it's also way beyond my skill level.  I'm hoping for something that can be done with a beginner's knowledge of HTML, javascript, and Google Analytics (or Urchin).